# writing functions in assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am writing code in assembler (nasm) and I want to include functions, at the moment I have

```
function0:

code

jmp return0
```

the function is called with a jump to function0 with the return linking to a label below where the function is called,
however this only works if the function is called once, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `call/ret`? Try looking at compiler-generated assembly to understand the basics.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(assuming NASM x86)

Use `call` in order to call the function and `ret` to return from the function.

What occurs when you type `call` is that the address of the next instruction is `push`ed into the stack. When `ret` is hit, it will `pop` that address off the stack and `jmp` to it.

```
func:
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, 10
    add eax, 5
    ret ;// essentially identical to: pop [register] -> jmp [register]


_start:
    call func
    mov ebx, eax ;// Address of this instruction is pushed onto the stack
    ;// ebx is now 15
```

Calling convention dictates that the `EAX` register should contain the return value. Also note that the [__cdecl calling convention](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions#CDECL) takes parameters on the stack. Take a look at the examples in the afore-linked page. The NASM function will set up its stack frame and take parameters from the stack in order to use in the function. The value is stored in `EAX`.

Comment: Calling convention varies from platform/processor to platform/processor. For example x86-64 attempts to pass a number of parameters in registers if possible before it falls back to the stack. _EAX_ doesn't always contain the return value, and again it depends on the Calling convention, and the type being returned.

Comment: Conventionally, EAX contains the return value (or reference to it) more often than not, especially in x86. I know that floating points are generally returned in the XMM registers as per most calling conventions, but yes, I am referring mostly to the cdecl and stdcall conventions since OP doesn't seem to be at the point of understanding various calling conventions yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new, very easy way to write functions in assembly (with many return values):

```
function:
    sub esp, ( 4 * ret_count)
    pushad
    mov ebp, esp

    ;code
    ;acces first argument with ( dword[ebp + 32 + (4*ret_count) + (4*arg_num)]
    ;write first return value with ( mov dword[ebp + 36 + (4*ret_pointer)]
    popad
    add esp, ( 4 * ret_count)
    ret
```

After that, you can access return values like this:

```
call function
mov eax, dword[esp] ; 1st ret
mov ebx, dword[esp - 4] ; 2nd ret

; or you can just pop them : 
pop eax
pop ebx
```